# Postgres - Cast to boolean

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, boolean

I'm trying to update a Postgres database to set a boolean but I'm getting the following error

> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need
>   to add explicit type casts.

I've cut down the table description to show it's structure.

```
       Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 archived           | boolean                     |
```

The column in the db is currently empty so I have no others to use as a comparison.

I've tried the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET archived=TRUE WHERE id=52;
UPDATE table_name SET archived='t' WHERE id=52;
UPDATE table_name SET archived='1' WHERE id=52;
UPDATE table_name SET archived='t'::boolean WHERE id=52;
```

Neither of these have worked.

How do I cast my UPDATE to a boolean?

UPDATE: full error message

```
play_mercury=# UPDATE opportunities SET archived=TRUE WHERE id=(52,55,35,17,36,22,7,2,27,15,10,9,13,5,34,40,30,23,21,8,26,18,3,42,25,20,41,28,19,14,39,44,16,24,4,33,54,47,29,38,64);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = record
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Please post the **full** error message (there should be something to indicate which cast it is complaining about) and the definition of the ID column. `UPDATE table_name SET archived=TRUE ..` is perfectly valid

Comment: All of your UPDATE formats work fine for me in Postgres 8.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the `WHERE id=(52,55,...)`

Use: `WHERE id IN (52,55,...)`

Comment: It's obvious you never tried `UPDATE ... WHERE id=52;` Please, next time, try to post the exact statement you try and error it gives you. Otherwise, you make things harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE` condition is wrong. You need to use IN instead of =

```
UPDATE opportunities 
  SET archived=TRUE 
WHERE id IN (52,55,35,17,36,22,7,2,27,15,10,9,13,5,34,40,30,23,21,8,26,18,3,42,25,20,41,28,19,14,39,44,16,24,4,33,54,47,29,38,64);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying this? Via plsql? 
According to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) those should be valid and this also works for me:

```
tmp=# create table bar (a boolean, b int);
CREATE TABLE
tmp=# insert into bar values (TRUE, 1);
INSERT 0 1
tmp=# update bar set a=false where b=1;
UPDATE 1
tmp=# \d bar
      Table "public.bar"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | boolean | 
 b      | integer |
```